# Memory error in Python while using sklearn

Tags: python, memory, scikit-learn, traceback

I am trying to test my logistic regression model but I get a memory error and cannot solve it. Is it because my sentences take too much space? I will appreciate any help.

From Line 267 in my code:

```
self.X, self.y = self.transform_to_dataset(training_sentences,_pos__sentences)
self.clf = Pipeline([
('vectorizer', DictVectorizer(sparse=False)),
('classifier', LogisticRegression())])
self.clf.fit(self.X, self.y)
```

And the error I get after running this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "tagger_lr_chunk.py", line 342, in <module>
tagger.train(data_dir + 'train.txt')
File "tagger_lr_chunk.py", line 271, in train
self.clf.fit(self.X, self.y)
File "/home/selub/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/pipeline.py", line 248, in fit
Xt, fit_params = self._fit(X, y, **fit_params)
File "/home/selub/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/pipeline.py", line 213, in _fit
**fit_params_steps[name])
File "/home/selub/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/memory.py", line 362, in __call__
return self.func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/home/selub/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/pipeline.py", line 581, in _fit_transform_one
res = transformer.fit_transform(X, y, **fit_params)
File "/home/selub/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/feature_extraction/dict_vectorizer.py", line 230, in fit_transform
return self._transform(X, fitting=True)
File "/home/selub/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/feature_extraction/dict_vectorizer.py", line 204, in _transform
result_matrix = result_matrix.toarray()
File "/home/selub/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/sparse/compressed.py", line 943, in toarray
out = self._process_toarray_args(order, out)
File "/home/selub/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/sparse/base.py", line 1130, in _process_toarray_args
return np.zeros(self.shape, dtype=self.dtype, order=order)
MemoryError
```

Comment: Python MemoryError means you've run out of memory.  I suspect that to help you further, we'll need to see a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this memory issue by changing paramater of DictVectorizer in order to allow producing scipy.sparse matrices

```
self.X, self.y = self.transform_to_dataset(training_sentences,_pos__sentences)
self.clf = Pipeline([
('vectorizer', DictVectorizer(sparse=True)),
('classifier', LogisticRegression())])
self.clf.fit(self.X, self.y)
```